# After subclassing QTableView an using keyPressEvent ive lost use of arrow keys. How can I easily use them to navigate while keeping the custom signal?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So as the title says, after subclassing QTableView to be able to use the return/enter key to select rows from the view, I've lost the ability to use up and down arrows to navigate the view . I'm able to use the keys in the subclass (as i can print when i press the up or down arrow) but having problems making the selected row move up and down with them. Is my best option to create custom signals for up and down and connect them with their own functions to force move the selected row?

This is my subclass:

```
class CustomQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):    
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.signal.emit()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            print("Up")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            print("Down")
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this

```
class CustomQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):    
signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):

    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        self.signal.emit()
    else:
        QtWidgets.QTableView.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: Looks better, tho I can't test it in my code any more

Answer (score 0):

This solved its self quite nicely. Ill add the code here in case anyone else ever face the same problem

Custom Widget (QTableView)

```
class CustomQTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):    
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    signal_up = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    signal_down = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.ScrollHint(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.signal.emit()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            self.signal_up.emit()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            self.signal_down.emit()
        else:
            pass
```

And the function i use to move the selected row with the arrow keys:

```
def arrowkey(self,num):
    try:
        selection_model = self.ui.vt_Produkt_Treff.selectionModel()
        indexes = selection_model.selectedIndexes()
        muh = indexes[0].row()
        self.ui.vt_Produkt_Treff.clearSelection()
        self.ui.vt_Produkt_Treff.selectRow(muh+ num)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass
```